# Runge-Kutta for coupled vector field in Python

Tags: python, simulation, physics, differential-equations

I want to solve the time-dependent Heisenberg equation of motion for a spin-lattice-system using Runge-Kutta in Python. But I'm open to any suggestion how to solve the equation.

Starting with a system of N*N classical vectors on triangular lattice in a 120° Structure (every vector is 120° rotated to his neighbors) with only nearest neighbor interactions by defining a matrix with (N,N,3) entries.

Normally one would expect that doing some excitation on the spins (in form of a time-dependent spin-flip) some propagation over the lattice would appear, but what I see is no movement of the vectors so far (or just some tiny bit). The equation looks like 
[image: equation]
but is in my case a bit simpler (source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.03778.pdf) . I use only one J and I have no magnetic field B. The localField is the first term in this equation:

```
def localField(J,S,i,j):
        n = len(S)
        h = []
        hx = - J*(S[(i - 1) % n,j][0]+S[(i + 1) % n,j][0] +S[i,(j - 1) % n][0] +S[(i - 1) % n,(j + 1) % n][0]+S[(i + 1) % n,(j - 1) % n][0] +S[i,(j + 1) %n][0]) 
        hy = - J*(S[(i - 1) % n,j][1]+S[(i + 1) % n,j][1] +S[i,(j - 1) % n][1] +S[(i - 1) % n,(j + 1) % n][1]+S[(i + 1) % n,(j - 1) % n][1] +S[i,(j + 1) %n][1])
        hz =- J*(S[(i - 1) % n,j][2]+S[(i + 1) % n,j][2] +S[i,(j - 1) % n][2] +S[(i - 1) % n,(j + 1) % n][2]+S[(i + 1) % n,(j - 1) % n][2] +S[i,(j + 1) %n][2]) 

        h.append(hx)
        h.append(hy)
        h.append(hz)
        return(h)
    def HeisenEqM2(conf,J1):
        S=np.copy(conf)
        n=len(S)
        conf_sum = np.zeros(3)
        Snew = np.zeros((n,n,3))
        locF = np.zeros(3)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):

                localFie = localField(J1,S,i,j)



                Snew[i,j] += np.cross(S[i,j],localFie)

        return(Snew)
```

Then I start rotating one spin in the middle of the lattice and want to see if a wave is propagating through the lattice (according to spin-wave-theory).

```
def circ_ex_2(omega,t,config):
    n = len(config)
    S = np.copy(config)

    i = int(n/2)
    j = int(n/2)

    S[i,j][0] += np.cos(omega*t)
    S[i,j][1] += np.sin(omega*t)
    S[i,j][2] += 0
    S = norm_rand(S)

    return(S)
```

**My idea:** This is my definition of the Runge-Kutta method. In the end I normalize my new spin configuration to ensure that the size of the vectors stays constant and calculate the energy to see what is happening:

```
def runge_kutta_4th(S,omega,J1,Tstart,Tmax,tsteps):
    n=len(S)

    S2 = np.copy(S)
    tt = np.linspace(Tstart,Tmax,tsteps)
    dt = (Tmax-Tstart)/tsteps

    en = []
    for i in range(tsteps):

        S1 = np.copy(circ_ex(omega,tt[i],S2))
        k1 = HeisenEqM2(S1,J1)
        k2 = HeisenEqM2(circ_ex(omega,tt[i]+dt/2,S1+ dt/2*k1) ,J1) 
        k3 = HeisenEqM2(circ_ex(omega,tt[i]+dt/2,S1+ dt/2*k2)  ,J1) 
        k4 = HeisenEqM2(circ_ex(omega,tt[i]+dt,S1+ dt*k3)  ,J1) 
        S2 =S1 +  dt*(1/6*k1 + 1/3*k2 + 1/3*k3 + 1/6*k4)

        S2 = norm_rand(S2)

        en.append(JEnergy(J1,S2)/n**2)
    return(S2,en)
```

**To reproduce the code:** If you want to reproduce the code you can start with the following spin-lattice system:

```
#defining a neel lattice
def neelM(nsize):
    X=np.ones((nsize,nsize))*np.pi/2
    x= np.pi/2
    for i in range(nsize):
        for j in range(nsize):
            X[i,j] += 2*np.pi/3*(i+2*j)
    P = polar(X)
    return(P)

#returning neel lattice as XY components 
def neelMXY(M):
    n = len(M[0])
    v = np.zeros((int(n**2),3))
    X = M[0].flatten()
    Y = M[1].flatten()
    for i in range(n**2):
        v[i,0] += X[i]
        v[i,1] += Y[i]
        v[i,2] = 0
    return(v)
```

It's called Neel-State and is the ground-state of the triangular Heisenberg Antiferromagnet. Then you also will need a normalization of spin vectors defined very simple:

```
def norm_rand(M):
    n = len(M)
    Mnew = np.zeros(np.shape(M))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            norm = np.linalg.norm(M[i,j])
            Mnew[i,j] += M[i,j]/norm
    return(Mnew)
```

To see where the energy of your system is I defined the Heisenberg energy which is just the scalar product of one vector with all of his neighbors.

```
def JEnergy(J,S):
    n=np.shape(S[1])[0]
    H=0
    counter = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):

            H += 1/2*J*(np.dot(S[i,j],S[(i - 1) % n,j])+np.dot(S[i,j],S[(i + 1) % n,j])+np.dot(S[i,j],S[i,(j - 1) % n])+np.dot(S[i,j],S[(i - 1) % n,(j + 1) % n])+np.dot(S[i,j],S[(i + 1) % n,(j - 1) % n])+np.dot(S[i,j],S[i,(j + 1) %n]))
            counter+=1
    return(H)
```

After all you can run the following:

```
neel24 = np.reshape(neelMXY(neelM(24)),(24,24,3))

rk24 = runge_kutta_4th(neel24,5*np.pi,1,0,10,10000)

Tt = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
list0 = []
for i in range(10000):
    list0.append(JEnergy(1,circ_ex(5*np.pi,Tt[i],iter24)))

plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10000),rk24[1])
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10000),np.dot(list0,1/24**2))
```

It shows that just flipping one spin in time has an larger effect than the Runge-Kutta method. But this cannot be the case, since over the cross-product in the equation of motion the change of one spin should affect over spins as well and leads therefore to an higher energy change. I have also ploted the vectors using `quiver`and it shows that the vectors doesn't change much over time.   This plot shows the energy:

[image]

It would be great if someone could help me. The problem should be possible to solve, since the paper above has done a similar thing but with an more complicated system.

Comment: This question may get more attention on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)